# NSData has no member arrayOfBytes in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, nsdata

In swift 2.3, I used `nsdata?.arrayOfBytes()`, but it does not work in swift 3.
Error: `Value of type 'NSData' has no member 'arrayOfBytes'`

Please help me.
Thanks for all.
**UPDATED**: Use `data?.bytes`.

Comment: Use `Data` in Swift 3. It conforms to `Sequence`